# Couchdb: is it possible to query a view from within another view?

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

I have a CouchDB database with the following type of documents, representing events that happen within a building:

```
{ person: 1
  timestamp: 1
  event: { type: enter
           room: b }
}
```

and

```
{ person: 2
  timestamp: 5
  event: { type: leave
           room: b }
}
```

The  problem that I want to solve is the following: I want to know the total amount of time that every other person spent in the same room as person 1. Note that any person can enter and leave many rooms at many different times. I honestly don't know whether MapReduce is the best paradigm for this, or if I should just export my data and write a separate script to figure this stuff out (although this is probably not a feasible solution for our production environment).

As a starting solution lets assume that all the data is sane, and thus someone entering a room will also leave that room at a later time. However, in a final solution this requirement will probably have to be relaxed, because some events may be missing.

I have thought of a potential solution, but I have no idea whether this is at all possible or how to do this in couchdb. Here is an outline.

1. Create a view that emits the following format, for every person **entering a room** event:

   `{ [room, person, timestamp], null }`
2. Create a view that emits `{ [room, timestamp], null}` for every time person 1 exits the room (could be for all people, but is unnecessary).
3. Create a view that for each exiting a room event for any person except person 1, does the following. In the mapping step:

   - *Queries the first view* to find the last timestamp when that person entered the room.
   - *Queries the first view* to find all times before the exiting the room event that person 1 entered that room
   - For each of those times, *queries the second view* to find all exit times for that room, and for each interval checks what the overlap is.
   - Sum these overlaps together and emit as `{ person, time }`

Reduce:
    for every person, sum all the times together.

However, this relies on me being able to figure out how to query a different view from within a view. Does anybody know if that is possible, and if so, how?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your need, but you may want to try using the changes feed to run a view that gets all the people in the room when person 1 leaves.  Then run your second view, this is assuming your events are being recorded on the same person document.   Hope this helps.  As far as your question, I don't think you can call a view within a view.

Comment: My problem is that I want to do it after everything has happened (everybody has left the building): I want to know the total time people spent in the same room together, so while I could do it (almost: have to check for every exit event too) with your solution for every room, I still need to sum them all together at the end. However, there is a second problem, in that I don't have person documents, but event documents. I thus have to relate different person IDs together (their entering and leaving events), and that would thus require a different view (to join all events by personID).

Comment: Is it possible to manage both a person document and event document, then monitor the _changes feed of event documents [enter, leave] per room, then update the person document with a time stamp on entry and on exit of each room.  and on exit calculate the total time in the room and apply it to the person document.   Then you should be able to create a view to key off of [room, person, total time].

Comment: At the moment I don't even have person documents. I guess that could be a solution, but person documents are going to get very large very quickly: entering and leaving a room are not the only events we capture. The solution I am looking at right now is to place all the processing in a list function. I am not sure that will work, but I'm going to give it a try and report back here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I have found for doing this within the CouchDB structure is by using a list function. I create a view that simply emits all documents with [building, timestamp] as key. This helps me query the view to ensure I have a single day and a single building, with startkey and endkey.

I now create a list function that simply takes all the documents returned by the view, and performs the processing in a javascript function. This bypasses the map-reduce framework for the most part, but was the only way I could think of doing this within the CouchDB framework. Obviously the same could be done with any other script instead of the list function, using CouchDB's RESTful API.